# template file for content header of a view

Tags: views, theming

I am using views 2. In views, it asks you for the title of the view and this title is displayed on the screen at 
div id=content -> div id=content-inner -> div id=content-header -> h1 id=title
I would like to know if there is a template file which I can modify that can modify this title (ie: add some text to it). I think I can do this with javascript or with css using :after, but I would like to use a template if is available.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood you want to  modify title of your views page.
This title is the title of entire page.
You can modify this title using [drupal_set_title('Your Title');](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7)

If you want to modify this title you can load current title first by [drupal_get_title()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_title/7) and then set new title.